# Unexpected behavior of sem_open

Tags: c, posix, semaphore

I have the following code:

```
// DIE is macro i defined for catching errors

semc = sem_open(sem_name, O_CREAT, 0644, 1);    
DIE(semc == SEM_FAILED, "sem_open");

unsigned int val;
rc = sem_getvalue(semc, &val);
DIE(rc == -1, "sem_getvalue");
printf("sem is %d\n" , val);
```

Although I initialized the semaphore with 1, the value printed is 0 ...
How can this be explained ?

Answer (score 2):

Specifying `O_CREAT` doesn't force it to create, it only creates the semaphore if it does not already exist.  Since you find that it doesn't take on your initialization value I would guess that `sem_name` already exists with value 0 at the time you call `sem_open`.

Comment: It does not exist, I give various names for the semaphore and the result is the same: it fails to initialize the semaphore with the value i want. If i put sem_open("constant_string", O_CREAT, 0644, 1) it retains the value 1, otherwise i give a string variable, it does not.

Comment: By the way, if you insist on the semaphore not already existing, you must add `O_EXCL` to the open flags.

Comment: @R if i add O_EXCL flag, it tells me all the time that the semaphore exists... although i put different names time to time!

Comment: @Madrugada, mind telling us what it was. Somebody else might learn from your experience.

Comment: I was trying to reinitialize something that was initialized before-in another program which i didnt have the source of.. so it just took the value it was init there, not mine....